# Deep neural network - How many layers?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning

I am trying to implement a multi-layer deep neural network (over 100 layers) for image recognition. As far as i can understand each layer learns specific features.

I am feeding 100x100 pixel color RGB facial images to a DNN and trying to capture nose, eyes etc.

But how do i decide on number of layers on  deep neural network?

I am using FANN c library for neural network.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Yoshua Bengio, Head of Montreal Institute for Learning Algorithms [remarks](http://qr.ae/RORbIj):

*"Very simple. Just keep adding layers until the test error does not improve anymore."*

A method recommended by Geoff Hinton is to add layers until you start to overfit your training set. Then you add dropout or another regularization method.

Comment: how to decide on number of neurons per layer?

Comment: For your task, your input layer should contain 100x100=10,000 neurons for each pixel, the output layer should contain the number of facial coordinates you wish to learn (e.g. "left_eye_center", ...), and the hidden layers should gradually decrease (perhaps try 6000 in first hidden layer and 3000 in the second; again it's a hyper-parameter to be optimised and is very dependent on dataset size). [This tutorial](http://danielnouri.org/notes/category/tutorial/) regarding your specific task should be useful (in particular, a CNN would likely be much better than just a standard fully-connected DNN).